# How to remove highlight around tableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a window with a tableView. The table always look highlighted around borders, as if it's an "active" text area. I can't find a setting to turn this off. Help!
(I still want selected items inside the table to have highlight.)

Comment: It would help if you posted some sample code

Comment: There is no relevant code behind it. I am just asking how to remove a "focus ring" around the tableView in IB. In Attributes Editor, setting Focus Ring to No does not do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it - I was setting Focus Ring of 'Scroll View' to None, instead of the Table View. Yes folks, I am learning!